# WorkManager not working periodically in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I was creating an android notification app which gives notification every 15 minutes after the alarm has been set.

it calls first time, and shows notification but workmanager not calling every 15 minutes.

```
 val myWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<ReminderWorker>(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build()

        WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
            .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("work", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE, myWorkRequest)
```

Comment: Use `AlarmManager` instead of `WorkManager`.

Comment: but it's not running background. are you sure alarm manager is needed? I already tried with it but it didn't work. I just want to show notification every 15 minutes , data from database.

Comment: I used alarm manager + broadcastreceiver , - android 11

Comment: Clone and run this repo you'll get it- 
https://github.com/alamincmt/android (SimpleAlarmClock-Demo Project)

Comment: @Al-Amin thanks. I will try, but still in doubt. because android 11 has any restrictions to make it work?

Comment: you need to add initialDelay to the build

 .setInitialDelay(15, TimeUnit.MINUTE)
something like this

Comment: is there any kotlin version

Comment: follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/77264413/4997704

Answer (score 1):

After many days i found a solutions for periodic work manager
Use time intervals of at least 1 hour. In document mentions minimum 15 minutes but it is not working don't why not mention in documents when i set 1 hours then it working.

```
  fun scheduleNotificationRepeated() {
    val constraints: Constraints = Constraints.Builder().apply {
        setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
    }.build()
    val request: PeriodicWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
        NotifyWork::class.java, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .setInitialDelay(2, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .build()
    val instanceWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance(this)
        instanceWorkManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
        "TAG_WORK_NAME",
        ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
        request
    )
}
```

Comment: Not working for me, using 8 hours delay with 30 minutes flex. Tested on Android 10 and 12

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use one time request to make this work. you can have one time request to be scheduled for once and when  that request is executed and its doWork() is called you can schedule another one for next 15  minutes and then so on like a recursion. thats pretty straight forward.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add initialDelay to the builder

```
 val myWorkRequest: PeriodicWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
        MySimpleWorker::class.java, 3, TimeUnit.HOURS, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .setInitialDelay(2, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .build()
```